# How to find lower bound on condition number of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

The condition number is given as follows:
 $c(B)=\|B\|\|B^{-1}\|$

My questions are:
1. Considering that $B$ is non singular, i have to show a lower bound on $c(B)$ for $B$
2. What is that lower bound if $B=I$?
3. I have this matrix $$C=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 &0.999 \\
        1 &1.001 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
need to evaluate its condition number using Matlab. **(I know that we can use "cond" command for this part, just do not know how")**
4. Need to find a vector v around which the solution to $Cv = b$ is not stable

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Note that if $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm, then $\|\textrm{some matrix product}\|\le\|B\|\|B^{-1}\|$.
2. $\|I\|=\|I\,I^{-1}\|$, so ...
3. `help cond`
4. Consider $v=(1,1)^T$. What is $b$? If we make a small change in $b$, so that $b$ becomes $(2,2)^T$, how would $v$ change? If we don't change $b$, but change the coefficients of $C$ slightly instead, so that $C$ becomes $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$, what happens then?